# Using 3D style slicing in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes a numpy array (A) as input. This array could be a 2d or a 3d array depending on a mathematical calculation. There is an integer m which could be any number, except when the array is 2D, the value of m will always be 0. I want to pass a silce of A to another function. Since A can be both 3D or 2D, I tried 3D style slicing.

```
def fun(A):
    ... some code
    ans = fun2(A[:,:,m]) #The value of m is 0 if A is 2D
```

This gives me an `IndexError` when A is 2D

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I want to pass the full 2D array to fun2 if A is 2D, like it happens in MATLAB. How can it be done in Python? I use Python 2.

Comment: MATLAB automatically extends dimensions at end as needed (order=F).  `numpy` performs its expansion at the start - at least when broadcasting.  But in indexing contexts like it does not add indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a good setup to use [`np.atleast_3d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_3d.html) as we can *force* it to be `3D` and then simply slice the m-th index along the last axis, like so -

```
np.atleast_3d(A)[...,m] # Or np.atleast_3d(A)[:,:,m]
```

It's still a view into the array, so no efficiency lost there!

**Case runs**

1) 2D :

```
In [160]: A = np.random.randint(11,99,(4,5))

In [161]: np.atleast_3d(A)[...,0]
Out[161]: 
array([[13, 84, 38, 15, 26],
       [64, 91, 29, 11, 48],
       [25, 66, 77, 14, 87],
       [59, 96, 98, 30, 88]])

In [162]: A
Out[162]: 
array([[13, 84, 38, 15, 26],
       [64, 91, 29, 11, 48],
       [25, 66, 77, 14, 87],
       [59, 96, 98, 30, 88]])
```

2) 3D :

```
In [163]: A = np.random.randint(11,99,(4,3,5))

In [164]: np.atleast_3d(A)[...,1]
Out[164]: 
array([[34, 81, 66],
       [56, 20, 25],
       [45, 36, 64],
       [82, 64, 31]])

In [165]: A[:,:,1]
Out[165]: 
array([[34, 81, 66],
       [56, 20, 25],
       [45, 36, 64],
       [82, 64, 31]])
```

Comment: Watch out for what `atleast_3d` does to 1D arrays - it converts an array of shape `(N,)` to `(1, N, 1)`, which may not be what you expect

Comment: @Eric Good point! Well OP isn't working with 1D and if there's 1D as input, the expected outcome isn't mentioned. The function that we are supposed to pass on the data to expects 2D data, which we are doing with `np.atleast_3d`, so I am guessing we might be okay there too!

Comment: Using `np.atleast3d` just hides the logic that decides whether to do `A[:,:m]` or `A[:,:,newaxis][:,:,m]`.